# Connecting AMP to Audio interface

Tags: recording, amplifiers, audio, pre-amp

I have the MOTU m2 to record my vocals through my Rode NT1 (XLR), I would like to connect my headphones (660s senneheiser) to a Topping A90 headphone amplfier, through a balanced connection.  How would that work?

***Would it go like this?:***

MOTU M2 1/4 trs line out --> Topping A90 line in XLR ---> Headphones (XLR balanced)

Another question being that the Topping a90 LINE IN is seperated into right and left channel XLR, what cable would I use?  Am i doing this all wrong?  I'm not even sure that this point

Comment: The MOTU has a headphone socket - Out of interest, why do you want to connect it onward to another headphone amp? Have you found the MOTU's headphone output to be wanting?

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems that you could connect the headphones with the 4.4mm balanced connector (on the right in this image: https://assets.sennheiser.com/img/25816/x1_desktop_sennheiser-hd-660s-cables-and-adapter.jpg) directly to the preamp (middle socket in the picture: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0225/2721/3642/products/apos-audio-topping-headphone-amp-topping-a90-headphone-amp-14617986629706_1200x900.jpg?v=1590600305)

It will matter more to have balanced connection between audio interface and headphone amplifier... and it will still have rather small impact. If you use $250 microphone and $200 audio interface buying $500 headphone amplifier seems overkill, unless you have specific reasons for that. There might be other places worth throwing cash at.